# Simpler way to convert all tables from InnoDB to MyISAM

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

Previously, I use this:

```
USE dbname;
ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE=MYISAM;
```

I'm looking for simpler way to convert all tables in a database, rather than writing every table name one by one

Comment: Simpler how?  That looks pretty simple to me.

Comment: Learn to use scripting to accomplish your goals.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not aware of any way to do this in mysql itself, but a simple shell script will do the job:

```
TABLES=$(mysql -pXXXXXXX -uXXXXXXX --skip-column-names -B -D $DB -e 'show tables')
for T in $TABLES
do
    mysql -pXXXXX -uXXXXX -D $DB -e "ALTER TABLE $T ENGINE=MYISAM"
done
```

Comment: how to disable foreign key check ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use MySQL to script it and execute it:

### This will convert every InnoDB table in database `dbname` to MyISAM

```
CONVERT_SCRIPT=Convert_dbname_InnoDB_to_MyISAM.sql
mysql -u... -p... -AN -e"SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' ENGINE=MyISAM;') FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='dbname' AND engine='InnoDB';" > ${CONVERT_SCRIPT}
mysql -u... -p... -A < ${CONVERT_SCRIPT}
```

### This will convert every InnoDB table to MyISAM

```
CONVERT_SCRIPT=Convert_InnoDB_to_MyISAM.sql
mysql -u... -p... -AN -e"SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' ENGINE=MyISAM;') FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine ='InnoDB';" > ${CONVERT_SCRIPT}
mysql -u... -p... -A < ${CONVERT_SCRIPT}
```

If you do not want the conversion of the tables to be replicated to Slaves, just put `SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;` as the first line. That way, you can test the conversion in a Master/Slave setup by converting only the Slave first and then the Master later.

### This will convert every InnoDB table in database `dbname` to MyISAM and not replicate to other servers

```
CONVERT_SCRIPT=Convert_dbname_InnoDB_to_MyISAM.sql
echo "SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;" > ${CONVERT_SCRIPT}
mysql -u... -p... -AN -e"SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' ENGINE=MyISAM;') FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='dbname' AND engine='InnoDB';" >> ${CONVERT_SCRIPT}
mysql -u... -p... -A < ${CONVERT_SCRIPT}
```

### This will convert every InnoDB table to MyISAM and not replicate to other servers

```
CONVERT_SCRIPT=Convert_InnoDB_to_MyISAM.sql
echo "SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;" > ${CONVERT_SCRIPT}
mysql -u... -p... -AN -e"SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' ENGINE=MyISAM;') FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine ='InnoDB';" >> ${CONVERT_SCRIPT}
mysql -u... -p... -A < ${CONVERT_SCRIPT}
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Going from MyIsam2InnoDB in real world you'll probably want `SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';`  somewhere to bypass the no_zero_date since mysql 5.7 - Source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192027/invalid-default-value-for-create-date-timestamp-field

Comment: Going from MyIsam2InnoDB in real world you'll probably want `SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';`  somewhere to bypass the no_zero_date since mysql 5.7 - Source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192027/invalid-default-value-for-create-date-timestamp-field

Answer (score 0):

For those who still having this issue, you can follow this way to do it, I found this answer in a website. It helps me a lot:

`shell> mysql -u username -p -e "SELECT concat('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME,' ENGINE=MYISAM;') FROM Information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' AND ENGINE = 'InnoDB' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'" | tail -n+2 >> alter.sql`

Update  `username` and `db_name` values with your own values.

Afet executing the script, it will save a file under name: `alter.sql`
Open the file and execute the content on your `phpmyadmin` or `mysql` command line.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

*I prefer one-liners for this type of stuff. This is a one-liner version of the most accepted answer.*

This works if you have your MySQL username and password set in `~/.my.cnf`.

```
D=your_db; for t in $(mysql $D -B -e 'SHOW TABLES'); do mysql $D -e "ALTER TABLE $t ENGINE=MyISAM"; done
```